# Lucene Search Highlight

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am searching text in pdf files by using Lucene search and highlight the results. The problem is when the searching word is in the start of the pdf the result highlight fine and return the results good. but when it hit the search in the middle or end or it do not highlight any result and do not return any result. please help me

thank you

Comment: Screenshots and code snippets would help

Comment: yes i can provide

Comment: @developer_117 can u please guide me how to make tokenstream I think it is the problem. it is always returning me the null.

Comment: is there a limit on the size of the document to analyze for highlighting? Is there a limit to the number of highlight snippets?

Comment: no, there is no limit the no of word can be changed according to the uploaded pdf file

Comment: Is this a Lucene.Net problem or a problem highlighting text in a PDF?

Comment: @RamblinRose thnx for reply, the problem is in Highlighting the matches. if the match found in the starting contents of pdf if return the results, but if the mathces are in later on pdf it do not return any result. The Problem is i think in the SimpleHTMLFragmenter object. because it takes int type parameter not the long type. what u say ??

Comment: @RanaMateen Sorry I'm unfamiliar with what you are using, I've always used Adobe's [Highlight File Format spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/HighlightFileFormat.pdf) to highlight match words in a PDF.

Comment: ok no Problem @RamblinRose I have done with it.